# How to fix icons not displaying at first load?

Tags: javascript, ajax, icons, jquery-events

****Problem**
**
I have built an mobile repair website with a custom repair module where customers can select a type of device, brand and a repair. When he wants to register a repair he goes in the nav-bar "reparatie aanmelden". In the next screen he can select a brand for example, when select it should display smartphone (iPhone), tablet (ipad), iWatch, iMac and Macbook. On the first load it displays only Iwatch, Smartphone and iMac. After reload it shows now iWatch, Tablet and Smartphone. The problems is that not all the icons for each type of device are loaded and randomly switch in order the ones which are displayed.

[first load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5XLR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A5oB.png)

**Details Url of the website:** (https://thesmartphone.nl/reparatie-aanmelden)

**What i did do**
I tried to add new types on the backend for example iPad en iPhone linked to devices. I doesn't display this.
I tried to change the url of the url of Smartphone, Tablet the same issue.
Further I checked my expire headers, cache flushed still the same issue.

I expected that it fix my problem and the icons would load at first load and displayed correctly

How Can I fix that icons of categories (Smartphone etc) are loaded on the first load.

And why loads it certain icons after a reload?

Comment: You're most likely missing an `ORDER BY` in your backend for that particular query. Can you show us how you build this particular query?

Comment: The response from the ajax call is responding with only three icons. That means the query is wrong. are you somehow limiting the number of icons returned?

Comment: I did not limit the amount of icons. For the query I used order by type "type of device". The weird part is when I use a different approach in the website by going to "merken" as brands  https://thesmartphone.nl/merken/ and choose the brand the missing icons are displayed but still in an random order. Is it possible that a post order plugin is conflicting? Recently installed wp sort order to rearrange post in the backend.